# How can I run npm-watch in development mode?

Tags: vue.js, npm, npm-watch

I have the following scripts setup in my `package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "dev": "vue-cli-service build --mode development",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "watch": "npm-watch"
  },
  "watch": {
    "build": {
      "patterns": [
        "src"
      ],
      "extensions": "js,jsx,vue,css"
    }
  },
```

Now I want to run `npm-watch` in `development mode`, but I don't know how to do it. I didn't find anything here: https://github.com/M-Zuber/npm-watch

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was as simple as adding `dev` after `npm-watch`:

```
"watch": "npm-watch dev"
```